# Why can't we access properties of PageModel derived class in asp-for via Model property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core

In the code-behind class `CreateModel` that inherits from `PageModel`, I have `Movie` property as follows.

```
[BindProperty]
public Movie Movie { get; set; }
```

`Movie` has many properties, such as `Title`, etc.

In the Razor page, tag helpers access `Movie.Title` as follows.

```
<label asp-for="Movie.Title" ></label>
<input asp-for="Movie.Title" />
<span asp-validation-for="Movie.Title" ></span>
```

## Question

Why can't we access `Movie.Title` via `Model` as follows?

```
<label asp-for="Model.Movie.Title" ></label>
<input asp-for="Model.Movie.Title" />
<span asp-validation-for="Model.Movie.Title" ></span>
```

In my understanding, `Model` is the "entry point" to access everything exchanged between view and controller and I know that Razor page is just a subset of MVC.

## Edit

The error message:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'CreateModel' does not contain a definition for 'Model' and no extension method 'Model' accepting a first argument of type 'CreateModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: I think it would be more better to add error to the question, it will increase of
 chances to get an answer!

Comment: Could you try using the `@`, e.g. `<label asp-for="@Model.Movie.Title" ></label>` for the 3 of them? Based on [Introduction to Tag Helpers in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro).

Comment: Sure :) glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this page describing Tag Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro), when you scroll down to find the @ symbol's usage, it's used to denote "start of code", so you just need to modify your lines to add it:

```
<label asp-for="@Model.Movie.Title" ></label>
<input asp-for="@Model.Movie.Title" />
<span asp-validation-for="@Model.Movie.Title" ></span>
```